# Increase counter and dynamically change variable that relies upon it

Tags: javascript, object

how can I increment a counter and expect the incremented counter to be changed within the object value that is using it as well?

Imagine:

```
var pizzaOrder = {
    id: "pizza",
    counter: 0,
    sentence: this.id + this.counter // first problem is here  
    // as I am getting NaN
};

pizzaOrder.counter++;

console.log(pizzaOrder.sentence);
```

expected output:

```
"pizza1";
```

Comment: you can make getSentence a function that returns the sum of id and counter, and use pizzaOrder.getSentence()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference an object that hasn't been finished being created yet like that, but it sounds like you'd want to use a getter here:

```js
var pizzaOrder = {
  id: "pizza",
  counter: 0,
  get sentence() {
    return this.id + this.counter;
  }
};
pizzaOrder.counter++;

console.log(pizzaOrder.sentence);
```

Comment: Why would we use a get if we can create it as a simple method/function?

Comment: Either way works, but OP looked like he was wanting to reference `sentence` as a plain property (which would work with a getter) rather than as a function call.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement using function inside of object like this

**DEMO**

```js
var pizzaOrder = {
  id: "pizza",
  counter: 0,
  getSentence: function() {
    return this.id + this.counter;
  }
};

pizzaOrder.counter++;

console.log(pizzaOrder.getSentence());
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` only works like this in *methods* or *getters/setters*. What you’re looking for is a getter:

```
var pizzaOrder = {
  id: "pizza",
  counter: 0,
  get sentence(){
    return this.id + this.counter;
  }
};

pizzaOrder.counter++;

console.log(pizzaOrder.sentence);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var pizzaOrder = {
  id : "pizza",
  counter : 0,
  sentence : function(){ return this.id+this.counter;  }
};
pizzaOrder.counter++;
console.log(pizzaOrder.sentence());
```